# Filtering out short fluctuations in binary array from digital input

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have a ttl signal represented as an array of 0/1 values. I want to smooth out any short spikes where the value changes for a very short time (for instance, less than 4 samples), which I know are noise.

For instance, if 4 is the minimum legitimate pulse length:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

should become

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

It seems a little difficult to come up with an exact replacement rule, though most cases are obvious subjectively. In general, it's not super important, as long as none of the short fluctuations are preserved.

Comment: Apart from the solution, imagine the data looks like this: `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, ..]` the first value is a `0` and although it's mostly 1s after that, there's never more than 3 - would you still want the entire series to be all 0s? (otherwise, the same question if the series had started with 4 zeroes)  Have you tried anything yourself at all? Run into specific problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply traverse the input array, forming another array that contains only the patterns you want.  It would be a rather simple state machine that just "buffers" the array items it goes through and weeds out any encountered runs of ones shorter than, say, four items, replacing them with zeros.

It could even be done with a regex that treats the input array as a string and replaces short runs of ones with zeros.  Though, such an approach would perhaps be less efficient.

Below is PHP code that demonstrates one way to implement the above-described state machine, in a form that isn't strictly optimized for speed or code size, but is written to be easily readable and understandable.  This PHP code can be rather easily translated into Python, which the OP probably expected, or into pretty much any other programming language.

Here's the code:

```php
define('SPIKE_LEN', 4);

$input  = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1];
$output = [];

$count     = count($input);
$run_start = null;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $is_one = ($input[$i] == 1);
    $is_end = ($i == $count - 1);

    if ($is_one && is_null($run_start))
        $run_start = $i;

    elseif ($is_one && !is_null($run_start) && !$is_end)
        continue;

    elseif ((!$is_one && !is_null($run_start))
        || ($is_one && $is_end)) {

        if ($i - $run_start > SPIKE_LEN)
            for ($j = $run_start; $j <= $i; ++$j)
                $output[$j] = $input[$j];
        else    // spike
            for ($j = $run_start; $j <= $i; ++$j)
                $output[$j] = 0;

        $run_start = null;
    }

    elseif (!$is_one && is_null($run_start))
        $output[$i] = $input[$i];

    else    // shouldn't be reached
        die("Internal error at position {$i} out of {$count}, value is {$input[$i]}\n");
}

echo('Input:  ' . join(' ', $input) . "\n");
echo('Output: ' . join(' ', $output) . "\n");
```

Here are also a couple of sample outputs produced by this code, for two different input arrays, the first of which is from the OP's question:

```
Input:  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 
Output: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

```
Input:  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 
Output: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This code could easily be improved to also record and print the run sizes in the input array and how many times each run size was found.  Such stats could provide a useful insight into the nature of the input signal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses a simple sliding window (with left-padding of first bit and right-padding of last bit) and majority voting on the bits in the window as a way of smoothing the signal:

```
signal   = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
expected = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

def filter_noise(signal, window_dim):
    left_pad = window_dim * [signal[0]]
    right_pad = window_dim * [signal[-1]]
    signal_padded = left_pad + signal + right_pad
    signal_filtered = []
    window_size = 2 * window_dim + 1
    for i in range(len(signal)):
        window = signal_padded[i:i+window_size]
        bit = int(sum(window) > window_dim)
        signal_filtered.append(bit)
    return signal_filtered

print(filter_noise(signal, window_dim=1))
```

prints

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

In this example, a window size of 3 happens to give the desired result, i.e. `filter_noise(signal, 1) == expected`.